# Where can I find the current Ripple version number?

Tags: ripple

[This page](https://github.com/rippleFoundation/ripple-client/issues/milestones) contains several milestones - versions 1,2,3.

How can I find what version is currently running on Ripple.com?

Comment: Wow, I never realized we had those!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the client at http://ripple.com/client, the version number is written at the bottom.

Currently it's 0.1.17